# Why the results are the same using linear programing and nonlinear programing in EXCEL

Tags: excel, statistics, linear-programming, solver, nonlinear-optimization

When I solving transshipment problem, I use excel solver. I found that the results are the same when I use linear programing and nonlinear programing. I cant understand why? Thank you!

1. Business Situation
   This project will help the company to solve transshipment problem to reach minimum total cost when distributing products from four sources (A, B, C and D) through three intermediary distribution centers (X, Y and Z) to four destinations (P, Q, R and S). Related information is provided as below:

• Source supply capacities (in units):

```
A: up to 32,500
B: up to 41,200
C: up to 18,000
D: up to 22,500
```

• Destination demands (in units):

```
P: 22,500
Q: 35,000
R: 39,700
S: 16,800
```

• Distribution center capacities (in units):

```
X, Y and Z: up to 50,000
```

• Transportation cost rates ($/unit):

```
From A: 23 to X, 17 to Y, 20 to Z
From B: 18 to X, 22 to Z, no service to Y
From C: 25 to Y, 20 to Z, no service to X
From D: 19 to X, 21 to Y, 17 to Z
From X: 8 to P, 12 to Q, 9 to R, no service to S
From Y: 10 to P, 12 to R, 8 to S, no service to Q
From Z: 14 to Q, 12 to R, 15 to S, no service to P
```

Comment: And thanks for an interesting problem, will be re-packaging this with a different story... Nice little linear problem, controlling balance.

Answer (score 2):

Not programmed or solved your problem, but I write, run and solve many problems similar to this.

The cheapest solution is the cheapest solution independant of the solver engine used.

If the problem is linear then that is the solver engine to use.

If the calculation path is not linear then one of the other engines has to be used, but the result of finding the cheapest still stands.

There are books, such as Practical Management Science by Albright and Winston which explain the uses of the different solver engines. There is also some detail in the excel help.